# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-6}$ using $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^{-6} = \frac{\pi^6}{960}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have shown that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^{-6} = \frac{\pi^6}{960}$, and from this I want to conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945}$, so I have been trying to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-6} =  \frac{64}{63}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^{-6}$$

but I can't think of a simple way of doing so. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you multiply $\sum n^{-6}$ by $2^{-6}$?

Comment: I get it thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S=\zeta(6)$ be the value of the sum you are trying to calculate. Notice that
$$\begin{align}
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^6}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}+\frac{1}{2^6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^6}{960}+\frac{S}{2^6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^6}{960}+\frac{S}{64}
\end{align}$$
Now you can easily solve the equation
$$S=\frac{\pi^6}{960}+\frac{S}{64}$$
to find the value of your series.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if
$S_m
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^{-m}
$
and
$T_m
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-m}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
T_m
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-m}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ((2k-1)^{-m}+(2k)^{-m})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-m}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k)^{-m}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^{-m}+2^{-m}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-m}\\
&=S_m+2^{-m}T_m\\
\text{so}\\
T_m
&=\dfrac{S_m}{1-2^{-m}}\\
&=\dfrac{2^mS_m}{2^m-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Yours is the case
$m=6$.